# What is this product called?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, boolean-algebra

Let $X$ be a finite set and let $2^X$ be its power set.  Let $Z$ be some ring (e.g. the complex numbers; it doesn't matter).

Suppose $f:2^X\to Z$ and $g:2^X\to Z$ are two functions from $2^X$ to $Z$.

A product $(f\ast g): 2^X\to Z$ can be defined like this:
$$\text{For $V\subseteq X$, }~~
 (f\ast g)(V) = \sum_{V_1\cup V_2=V} f(V_1)g(V_2).$$
(The sum is over all pairs $V_1,V_2\subseteq X$ such that $V_1\cup V_2=V$.)

**My question is:** What is this product called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary union operation makes $2^X$ into a *semigroup*. Now, the product you describe is usually called *convolution*, and together with pointwise addition in makes the set of functions $2^X \rightarrow Z$ into a new ring, called the *semigroup ring* $Z[2^X]$. Note that there can be problems in case $X$ is infinite - you'll have to restrict the support of functions involved in order to avoid infinite sums.

Comment: Thanks! Have you seen a specific name for a semigroup ring formed using this particular semigroup?  I imaging it is used in the theory of boolean functions.

Comment: @Nought Unfortunatelly, I haven't seen any special name for this specific case.